# Hide a specific series legend in a column chart with multiple series

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, chartkick

I'm trying to create a chart using Chartkick that has multiple series of data. The thing is that the two sets represent the same data points at different points in the year, so the legend has the labels duplicated. Is there a way to hide one of them by series?

Here's what my [current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPojp.png) looks like. (The left bar represents the beginning of the year & the right represents the end of the year.)

This is the code for my chart right now: (for testing purposes, the same data hash is used for both sets)

```
total_effort_data = [
            { name: "Academic", data: academic_hash, stack: "9/1" },
            { name: "Administrative", data: administrative_hash, stack: "9/1" },
            { name: "Clinical", data: clinical_hash, stack: "9/1" },
            { name: "Research", data: research_hash, stack: "9/1"} ,
    
            { name: "Academic", data: academic_hash, stack: "8/31" },
            { name: "Administrative", data: administrative_hash, stack: "8/31" },
            { name: "Clinical", data: clinical_hash, stack: "8/31" },
            { name: "Research", data: research_hash, stack: "8/31" }, ]
...
<%= column_chart total_effort_chart_path,
             stacked: true, legend: "top", suffix: "%", max: 100,
             colors: ["#FFDB80", "#F7A791", "#C8EA80", "#CAE9F4"] %>
```

And, on a side note, is it possible to add the "9/1" & "8/31" labels to below the axis under each column (above the year range)?

Comment: Can you tell what you have tried in fiddle?

Comment: @KrishnaKanth I'm not familiar with using fiddle. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This is the example of fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/afabbro/vrVAP/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2gdv5893/2/ I figured out how to hide the series here (using the series option `showInLegend: false`), but not sure how where that would apply in my rails code. Also, I would like for the legend to toggle both bars of the chart, as opposed to just one set.

Answer (score 0):

Use `showInLegend` and `linkedTo` properties:

```
    series: [..., {
        data: [3, 2, 1],
        showInLegend: false,
        linkedTo: 'series1'
    }]
```

It should probably look like below in your code:

```
total_effort_data = [
        { name: "Academic", data: academic_hash, stack: "9/1", id: "academic" },
        ...,

        { name: "Academic", data: academic_hash, stack: "8/31", showInLegend: false, linkedTo: "academic" },
        ...
]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ocxyfv42/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.showInLegend

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.linkedTo

Comment: Tried adding those three fields to my code, but no luck. I had tried adding the `showInLegend` field earlier, but not sure why it's not working. Works like a charm in jsfiddle though

Comment: Hi @dgonz234, So it probably works differently in Chartkick. You can directly contact with Chartkick authors: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues